# Robot Test Cannot find iframe in IE Browser. But finds it just fine in Chrome browser

Tags: robotframework

So due to some recent code changes in the UI I am testing, my Robot tests are failing to locate objects on a particular page. So after some trial and error I got Chrome browser to work by telling my test to (Select Frame xxxxx) then the test can find the objects and select and or use them as needed.

But running the same exact test in IE browser fails and says the element with locator "xxxx" not found. Where xxx is my frame name.
If i comment out the Select Frame code and run my test in IE or chrome is says it cant find the locator its trying to click on.

I have pulled my hair out trying to figure it out. I have updated the IE driver, tried slowing down the test and wait for element is visible, or enabled  all fail in IE

I can manually select the frame in IE through the F12 dev tools. But Robot cant find it. and I am at a lost

example code

```
Click Element ${MYmenu}
Click Element ${MySubMenu}
### NOTE New page opens after Sub menu is selected
Select Frame   xxxxxxxx
#### this Select Frame Fails in IE but works fine in Chrome
```

I expect IE to be able to select the Frame. then continue on selecting or using objects on that page

IE browser fails and says the element with locator "xxxx" not found. Where xxx is my frame name.

If i comment out the Select Frame code and run my tests in IE or chrome is says it cant find the locator its trying to click on.

Comment: Maybe you should use some delay before calling `Select Frame`.

Comment: Helio, I have already tried that still nothing

Comment: Other possibility is to use `Mouse Over`.

Answer (score 0):

Try downgrading installed selenium library and/or installed robotframework version. Also you can try downgrade IE driver.